# Manager line-height per font-size with styled system

Tags: css, reactjs, components, styling, styled-components

Styled components has a compose utility to combine multiple Styled System functions in a single component. I want to compose the lineHeight and fontSize together based on the default array.

Instead of doing:

```
  <Heading type="h1"
     fontSize={[ 1, 2, 3 ]}
     lineHeight={[1 , 2, 3 ]}
     color={theme.colors.heading.tinted}
  >
```

I want to achieve only a font prop that has the fontSize and lineHeight combined.

```
<Heading type="h1"
     font={[ 1, 2, 3 ]}
     color={theme.colors.heading.tinted}
  >
```

Heading.jsx

```
const Element = styled('div')(
    space,
    color,
    compose(
        fontSize,
        lineHeight
    )
);
```

theme.js

```
const theme = {
    fontSizes: [11, 13, 16, 23, 29, 37, 47, 76, 97],
    lineHeights: ['12px', '12px', '12px', '32px', '32px', '40px', '48px', '56px', '72px', '80px', '104px']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a codesandbox example with your requirements:
**Whole file is here:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-component-basic-j3zpx

```
<Title font={[50, 45]}>
        This is a heading includes first array index for font size and second array for line height.

      </Title>
```

**styled css:**

```
export const Title = styled.h1`
  color: red;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  ${props =>
    props.font &&
    css`
      font-size: ${props => (props.font[0] ? `${props.font[0]}px` : "20px")};
      line-height: ${props => (props.font[1] ? `${props.font[1]}px` : "30px")};
    `}
`;
```

Comment: @Marc Please let me know. Is this you wanted. Please upvote the answer and if it's the correct answer then check is as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: I had this solution with styled-components, right now i am using styled system. Styled-system makes use of a theme. The value that you give the props should be in index of the two arrays in the theme file. 
If you say `fontSize={[ 1, 2, 3 ]}` it looks in the `theme.js` and uses for first breakpoint index 1 in the array. So that is fontsize 13, and for the second breakpoint fontsize 16. Instead of giving these values to the fontSize and lineHeight seperated i want to combine it to one props that uses the value for both arrays

https://styled-system.com/table#typography

Comment: I think fontSize={[1,2]} these breakpoints are for responsive styles https://styled-system.com/responsive-styles.

I think what you want is something with custom styles https://styled-system.com/custom-props